# Magento 2 Images Not Showing on Product Detail page Please Advice

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have installed Magento 2.1.6 and had lot's of products over it. then i download fresh copy of magento 2.1.7 from magento market place and extracted and used my previous database that was had lot's of products and order histories etc.

the website start working fine . 
now i migrate Media folder from old website directory to new website directory same in pub folder

now images start working fine. but when i see on product detail page images not showing else all images showing any help?

Comment: I can imagine that clearing the Magento caches (and possibly varnish if you use it) might help.

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: u can try  bin/magento catalog:images:resize  if version updated

Answer (score 2):

you have not generated the static view files.

root > var > cache > DELETE ALL

root > var > page_cache > DELETE ALL

root > var > session > DELETE ALL

root > var > view_preprocessed > DELETE ALL

root > pub > static > delete all folder(not delete .HTACCESS)

After below command apply.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: good effort but this not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
(1) you have to check your browser console to see any require js issue.
(2) Give permission pub/media folder sudo chmod 777 -R pub/media/
```

Answer (score 1):

please check below link. I hope its working

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Images-not-loading-on-product-View-page-Magento-2-2-5/td-p/99439

https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/product-page-image-not-loading-after-upgrading-magento-to-2-2-4-629

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
2. Clear cache and reindex
3. Give correct permissions for pub folder.